# How to add a binary variable to a data frame based on another variable in the data frame in r?

Tags: r, performance, dataframe

My data (train) is a 443402 x 27 data frame and I have initialized a new binary variable train$researchedplan, to "1". There are 64,673 unique train$customer_ID's (each customer is entered a random amount of times in the data frame - but in order. i.e. the first customer has the first 9 rows, the second customer has the next 6, etc.).

```
> train[1:20,c(1,27)]
> customer_ID researchedplan
1     10000000              1
2     10000000              1
3     10000000              1
4     10000000              1
5     10000000              1
6     10000000              1
7     10000000              1
8     10000000              1
9     10000000              1
10    10000005              1
11    10000005              1
12    10000005              1
13    10000005              1
14    10000005              1
15    10000005              1
24    10000013              1
25    10000013              1
26    10000013              1
27    10000013              1
28    10000014              1
```

I also have a vector (diff_than_researched) that comprises of a string of some unique train$customer_ID's, identifying which customers did not research a particular plan. 
For the strings in diff_than_researched that match the strings in train$customer_ID, I would like train$researchedplan for all entries for the customer to be "0". 
e.g.:

```
> head(diff_than_researched)
>[1] "10000019" "10000033" "10000036" "10000037" "10000055" "10000075"
```

so, for all of the "10000019" entries, I would like train$researchedplan to equal "0".

Now, I can do this all with a "for loop", but it takes too long to loop through so many entries:

> for(i in 1:17210) { 
>     train$researchedplan[train$customer_ID == diff_than_researched[i]] <- 0
>   }

Comment: `train$researchedplan <- as.numeric(!train$customer_ID %in% diff_than_researched)`

Comment: @JakeBurkhead why is `!` applied after the evaluation of `%in%` and not as `!train$customer`?

Comment: @rawr [operator precedence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html). `special operators (including %% and %/%)` come before `! negation`

Comment: never paid attention to that. good info

Comment: @jake looks like an answer - please copy/paste to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using slightly different data for readability and to get some 0s in researched plan.

```
train

##    customer_ID
## 1     10000000
## 10    10000005
## 24    10000013
## 28    10000014
## 5     10000019    

train$researchedplan <- as.numeric(!train$customer_ID %in% diff_than_researched)

##    customer_ID researchedplan
## 1     10000000              1
## 10    10000005              1
## 24    10000013              1
## 28    10000014              1
## 5     10000019              0
```

As noted by @rawr in the comments this first checks whether each `customer_ID` is in `diff_than_researched` then negates that logical vector due to [operator precedence](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Syntax.html).